# Добавить своё приложение в список "Email сервисов"

Tags: java, android

Как добавить своё Android приложение в этот список?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что для этого нужно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

добавить одной из ваших активити вот такие интент фильтры

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
    <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: В AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Lesperanza ага

Comment: А как получить текст сообщения email в самой Activity? Допустим вот Activity запустилась. В ней есть несколько EditText. И что сделать, чтобы в определённом EditText появился текст сообщения?

Comment: @Lesperanza а это вы можете загуглить и найти, я бы так и сделал :)